# Possible to use screen lock as timeout?

Tags: lock-screen, productivity

What I'd like to do is lock the screen and have it wait a set amount of time (eg 20 mins) before it lets me log back in - so I make myself to have a break from the computer.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks

EDIT: Thanks for the suggestions - but I don't actually want something to remind me to take scheduled breaks. More something I can click when I realise I'm getting distracted and it'll immediately lock the screen for a fixed amount of time. Or even just lock screen if I can find a way to stop it letting me log in for 20 mins or so.

Comment: See also: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/drwright-for-ubuntu-schedules-regular-breaks-from-working

Comment: @Braiam No, that's different.

Comment: Wait, now that I read it better... isn't just pressing the "username" in the corner, then hit Lock Up the solution?